# How to Automatically add thousand separators for every number in a string?

Tags: string, kotlin, digit-separator

How can i create a thousand separator for every number which is in my string?

So for example this string:

```
string = "123456,78+1234"
```

should be displayed as:

```
TextView = "123.456,78+1.234"
```

And the string should be editable, so the thousand separator should adapt when i remove or add a digit.

I have already read all the posts I could find about it, but I could never find an up-to-date working answer. So I would be really grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your question contains two sub-questions:

**A.** You want to add thousand separators to a string which contains a group of numbers.

**B.** You want it to change.

And the answers are:

**A:** In your example there's `,` as a delimiter, so you need to split the string using this delimiter to an array of strings.

Then iterate over them and have your dots added to every `3n`th index of their characters; you can also use `String.format("%,d", substr.toLong())`.

Lastly, append all of the strings back together with `,` as the separator.

**B:** This one can be done in different ways. You may store the original string somewhere and observe it, so when it changes it goes to the function which does **A**, and use the function result the way you like (which I suppose is to be set in a TextView).